# Is there an opposite to the "Weather Boost"?

Tags: pokemon-go

So, depending on the weather, certain Pokemon gain a "Weather Boost", giving them higher CPs, making them harder to catch, spawning more regularly, reward more stardust, etc. For example, on Sunny Days, Fire types gain the Weather Boost.

However, I was wondering if there was an opposite of this? So, for example when it's raining, Fire types receive a debuff, potentially caucusing them to spawn with lower than average CPs and such?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unlike the main series, where the weather may provide negative effects based on the Pokémon’s typing or lack there of, there are no hinderances with catching or battling based on the weather.

As far as I am aware, the only debuffs that currently exist in Pokémon Go are specific charge moves, like Close Combat, which reduces your stats in PvP.